# Zu ihrer Beziehung zu stehen

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am translating from German and have this sentence:

> Und wenn er morgen sterben sollte, dann würde sie nach ihrem Abschluss erfahren, dass er vorgehabt hatte, so bald wie möglich zu ihrer Beziehung zu stehen.

I am not sure what *"zu ihrer Beziehung zu stehen"* means - could someone explain?

Comment: What do you think it means?

Comment: _"to adhere their relationship"_ seems to be the most probable good translation for ,me. But I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: I'd say he planned to confess his love - make their relationship public.

Comment: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/stehen meaning 15.

Answer (score 1):

And if he should die tomorrow, she would learn, after her graduation, that he planned to stand true to their relationship as soon as possible.

[roughly translated, nice english surely sounds different ^^]

It seems to me their relationship was somehow a secret. In this case many ppl. deny the fact they are in a relationship (and graduation assumes the girl to be young - too young maybe?). So "zur Beziehung stehen" means something like coming out.

Answer (score 0):

"Stehen zu" has several meanings.

In this context likely this would be something like...

"And if he were to die tomorrow, she would find out after her graduation that he had planned to commit to their relationship as early as possible".

So, in my opinion "stehen zu" in this context is "to commit to".